# Fastcgi app blocking on FCGX_Finish_r in combination with apache

Tags: c++, apache, fastcgi

I have a fastcgi app running several hundred requests per second.  Most of the requests finish in a millisecond or less, but some are taking up more than half a second.  When outputting some more timing information, I was able to pin down the problem to calling `FCGX_Finish_r`.

As far as I can see, this call will flush all data written to apache (mod_fastcgi).  But why is it blocking?

I tried narrowing it down to the response size, but although the longest response durations (i.e. 2seconds) are with the largest responses (i.e. 120kb), those same large responses can be as short as 16ms.

-- EDIT --
I ran some more numbers, and the bad timings seem to occur once the responses are bigger than 16k. Although from that point on, there is no correlation between the size and the duration of the slow responses.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with high latency calls to FCGX_Finish_r() at moderate load.  I am using a unix socket between my app and nginx.  I can find no correlation between response size and latency; it appears to be contention somewhere, but not related to the size of the flush buffer.  Is your FCGI app multithreaded?  I have noticed that the latency spikes tend to fall into groups; it appears that something is blocking the socket, and multiple threads pile up behind it.  No luck yet finding the culprit.

Comment: Yes, my app is multithreaded. I noticed previously that the number of threads was too low (2, same as the number of cpu-cores): requests were piling up while the slow response couldn't get out.  Now set to 16, this problem has gone away.  Have you tried printing out the thread id for those slow responses that are piling up?

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed your issue.  I can see how running a low number of application threads would cause incoming calls to block, but it's not obvious to me how increasing the number of threads would prevent FCFX_Finish_r from blocking.  

I'm running 24 threads at the moment.  Printing thread ID doesn't show any pattern that I can see - the blocked thread appears random.  Interestingly, the time that it blocks seems to fall into discrete bands -- of ~30ms or ~60ms.  I'd suspect Nagle but it is too inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry, but the FCGX_Finish_r problem isn't fixed. I had noticed a cascading effect due to the insufficient number of threads, which is now gone. My timings are nowhere near consistent, though.

Comment: I've tried setting `net.core.rmem_default` and `net.core.wmem_default` in `sysctl.conf` to 256k, and verified that the FCGI socket reflects those properties.  Switching between a blocking vs. nonblocking socket seems to have no effect on the apparent blocking writes.  Your observation of a 16k response size threshold implies a buffer size issue.  My largest responses are a little over 8k, also implying a buffer size issue.  I've tried increasing the number of fastcgi buffers in nginx also with no luck.

Comment: The fastcgi library uses a buffer of 64k, mod_fastcgi uses buffers of 8k, nginx uses 4k or 8k (see here: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_buffers).  When checking for size/time correspondance, I first split up by response size in blocks of 8k, then plotted the timing distribution for each block.

Comment: I solved my issue - it turned out to have little to do with FCGI and much to do with using an 4096-bit SSL certificate and the heavy processing associated with it.  The nginx workers were too busy doing SSL work to service the `FCGX_Finish_r` reads.  Changing to a 2048-bit SSL cert cut CPU in half and the write blocking disappeared.

Comment: Sadly, cpu isn't my bottleneck: I'm hardly using 20%. But good for you! :)